# Selecting loops crashes Blender 2.71 on mac

Tags: modeling, osx

Has anyone else noticed that selecting an edge loop by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd> on it crashes in version 2.71 on a mac?  Reverted back to 2.7 and it works just fine.

Comment: Create a bug report :) Also, try alt+shift+rmb

Comment: If Blender crashes then it's automatically a bug report situation.  Feel free to let them know. This is the sort of problem that gets fixed right away once it's reported.